# iOS 11.3.1 Mail app doesn't shown new mail until the iPhone is rebooted - any cure?

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, email, gmail

I have an iPhone 6s running iOS 11.3.1.  The Mail app is able to download and display e-mail from my GMail account.  However, e-mail to my account at register.com is frequently not displayed until I have powered off the phone and powered it back on.  The webmail service at register.com shows that the e-mails have been received, and the iPhone actually shows a little message saying "Downloading 5 of 5" or whatever, but the e-mails never appear.

We all know that 11.3.1 is something of a failed release, but has anyone else experienced this problem and found a solution that doesn't involve turning the phone off and on to receive new mail?

Comment: I have 11.3.1 on 6 iOS devices in my family and none of them have this problem with any email provider using the stock Mail app.  I don't see this as being 'failed release' or related to the release at all.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to try

1. Delete the Account from your phone and re add it.
2. Go into Settings > General > Reset and reset the network settings

You will lose the WiFi networks you have already been on and authenticated to but all you have to do is re-connect and re-authenticate.

3. Failing the above I would back up the phone (password protect the backup so you don't lose your saved passwords.) Wipe it (Settings > General > Reset > Erase all content and settings) and then restore from the backup you just made.

Comment: if the on-board erase fails to address the issue, then connecting the device to iTunes (Mac or PC) and restoring to factory settings will be more likely to address these issues, and will update the device to a newer iOS in the process.